# Not able to upload more than 5 mb file in Sharepoint from Apex Salesforce

Tags: apex, integration, fileupload, sharepoint

I am using Sharepoint to upload file from Salesforce, I have integrated both system via Rest API.
Below 5 mb files it's working fine, but for file larger than this I am not able to upload it.
I know that we can use @future to increase the heap size to 12 mb, which I already did, still it's not uploading.

I am getting response status code "200" but null response body.
I used multipart upload, single but it didn't work.

Any help will be well appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: please see [ask] and then [edit] to show the exact REST endpoint/payload you are using